# How to create action priority matrix chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following set of data:

[image]

I would like to create a Scatter chart, where LoE would be X axis, going from 1-5, and Impact would be Y axis, also 1-5. The dots would be Actions, positioned on the chart based on their combination of LoE and Impact values. So, in example, there would be an Action 5 dot, positioned in the top right part of the chart, due to its 5/5 value.

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried using normal scattered chart, but I'm not sure how to indicate that columns B and C are measuremets of column A in the chart. Tried different combos in the data selector, but none seemed to work. I also tried pivot chart, but that also didn't work since pivot chart can't be scattered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the two columns of data
2. Insert a scatter chart
3. Right-click on the chart and choose "Select Data"
4. Add a new series with `A2:A6` as series label, `B2:B6` as X values and `C2:C6` as Y values

[image]

5. Remove any other series that may be present
6. Add data labels and format them so they use the values in `A2:A6`

[image]

You should have something like this:

[image]